# Is possible to keep session even after the browser is closed?

Tags: php, session

Could anyone tell how to maintain a session (in PHP) so that the session contains are preserved and are accessible even after the browser is restarted.

In general a session expires with the closing of a browser, but I want the session NOT TO BE CLOSED so that the session data's can be accessed the next time the browser is used.

Comment: That stops being session data and starts being more persistent data (in like a DB) surely?

Comment: How do you record session - with a cookie? You'll need to make that cookie persist beyond the browser session then - sorry I can't tell you what specificially you need to do for PHP. If you're using cookieless sessions by adding IDs to your URLs I'm not sure if you can do this unless you can force the user to return to the same URL.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [`session_set_cookie_parameters()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to give the session cookie a non-zero lifetime before starting the session, or set [`session.cookie_lifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) to non-zero.

Answer (score 10):

It's oxymoron.
Session stands for "until browser is closed".
Session is something that *expires.*
If you don't want it to be expired, you're probably don't want a session at all.

You are probably messing session with cookie or database.

Comment: Sessions work with cookies, which are deleted when the browser is closed, _unless_ they have a specific life-time.

Comment: @elusive 1. cookie is not the only thing responsible for the session lifetime. 2. I am talking of term "session", not specific PHP mechanism. but PHP session ideology of course follows this definition. You can disregard that behavior, but you will just spoil yourself.

Comment: Cookies are called *session cookies* if they expire when the browser session expires. And that is the case when the browser is closed. But such a session cookie does not need to contain a session ID.

Comment: The cookie should not be responsible for the session lifetime at all; it’s the server that maintains the session, not the client.

Comment: it's surprising that the user with such a big reputation is so unfamiliar with contemporary session implementations

Answer (score 4):

Session in php (and in most web technologies) work like this :

You store a session id in a cookie on the client computer.

When the client come to your site he send you the session id.

The server find the session datas in a file with the session id and load it.

So closing the browser has not effect on the session, but if the browser empty the cookie when you close it (I don't think any browser do such a thing).

If you wana be sure the user is always logged in, you can store it's user/password in his cookies but it's not really safe.

Comment: Or you can store a cryptographic token in the cookies instead.

Comment: Why it's not safe? It's absolutely safe if you use cookies safely and cleverly.

Comment: @hey : it's not safe : I go on your computer, I go to the cookies directory and I read your login informations, and I'm 99% sure that you use these informations in some other websites. If it's a public computer it's even funnier. @ignacio : indeed you can create your own session system.

Comment: If you had physical access to my machine, Cookies would be the least of my worries.

Comment: I think so, I could check your bank account, or your pro email. And in a public computer anyone can see cookies from previous users.

Comment: well if  you had access to my pc, then worse it to go to chrome settings, open the password panels and there it is all the passwords

Comment: @Miguel not anymore, AFAIK you are required to enter the device password to view them now.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and best i have found is that instead of just session_start we should input this on each page there is a session

```
$expire = 365*24*3600; // We choose a one year duration

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $expire);

session_start(); //We start the session 

setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$expire); 
//Set a session cookies to the one year duration
```

Comment: This creates a new session every time the page loads

Comment: So all you have to do is to check whether there was not an existing session. That should not be hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: (see [`session_set_cookie_parameters()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and [`session_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php))

```
// long long time
$sessionTime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
$sessionName = "my_session";
session_set_cookie_params($sessionTime);
session_name($sessionName);
session_start();

if (isset($_COOKIE[$sessionName])) {
    setcookie($sessionName, $_COOKIE[$sessionName], time() + $sessionTime, "/");
}
```

For `$sessionTime`, also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3290424/2603230)

Answer (score 0):

This work!

```
// long long time
$sessionTime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
$sessionName = "PHPSNAME";
session_set_cookie_params($sessionTime);
session_name($sessionName);
session_start();
if (isset($_COOKIE[$sessionName])) {
    setcookie($sessionName, $_COOKIE[$sessionName], time() + $sessionTime, "/");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done if you use cookies instead of sessions.

Comment: Well, what I meant was using setcookie instead of session_start

Comment: with url params (or whatever place in the http request), but it's not the default behavior and I think that here we are looking at a normal case. But you're right indeed