# Session Cookie will not set correctly

Tags: php

I have all the ini_set variables correctly set for a 30 day cookie, the Session_cookie_params is the same way, yet everything I do still has the session cookie expiring when the browser closes.  Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set session_cookie_params before starting your session.

See here:
[Is possible to keep session even after the browser is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684620/is-possible-to-keep-session-even-after-the-browser-is-closed)

Comment: That's the thing.  It is set properly, and yet I get this problem.

Comment: Instead of using the session, trying using your own cookies.