# Keep session after browser is closed

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, session-timeout

I want to be able to keep a PHP session, even after the browser has been closed. I know on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684620/is-possible-to-keep-session-even-after-the-browser-is-closed) question, they suggested using the *session_set_cookie_parameters()* parameter, but I am unable to find a working example of this that doesn't expire and works across all directory on my domain. If someone could help out, it would be amazing.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using cookies because they are client side, and therefore can be edited or modified by the client; henceforth making it easier for people to gain unauthorised access to an others account.

Comment: so store the session id in the cookie and recreate when they come back

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session stands for "until browser is closed".
Session is something that expires.
If you don't want it to be expired, you're probably don't want a session at all. You better read on [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) too. I guess that's what you need.

But You can use [session_set_cookie_parameters()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to give the session cookie a non-zero lifetime before starting the session, or set [session.cookie_lifetim](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)e to non-zero.

Remeber `session_set_cookie_params()` needs to be called before session_start() for every single page request. [Read more](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/php/5963.asp)

***Code:***

```
<?php 

session_set_cookie_params(30 * 60, "/");
session_start();
print_r(session_get_cookie_params());

?>
```

***Output:***

Array ( [lifetime] => 1800 [path] => / [domain] => [secure] => )

***Explanation:***

Sets the cookie to expire after 30 minutes and be available anywhere on the site.

Comment: Ah, okay. So it is probably just better to use cookies then?

Comment: yes it could be, it depends on your requirement. Read the links which will helps you to figure out what you need

Answer (score 1):

Use `session_set_cookie_parameters()` with a non zero value before session starts.

Refer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).