# Login PHP Session gets cleared when chrome closes, persistent in Firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

My login script:

```
if (login_user($user_login, $password)){//Login check is verified
            ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
            ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);

            session_start();
            $user = get_user($user_login);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
```

When I login for testing, the session is active between different pages on both Firefox and Chrome. No problems there.

Though, when I restart the browser, the Login session is lost in Chrome, whilist I'm still logged in in Firefox.

I've tried to google the issue but the main pointed out issue is a missing favicon which I have in my root folder.

EDIT

- I don't know if it helps, but I've found a cookie in Chrome called
  PHPSESSID (related to my website) and it basically says "Expires when
  browser closes".
- The same cookie, PHPSESSID, expires on Friday, May 3, 2019, 2:12:28 AM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is possible to keep session even after the browser is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684620/is-possible-to-keep-session-even-after-the-browser-is-closed)

Comment: I did set session.cookie_lifetime though. I don't understand why it is persistent in Firefox but not in Chrome?
I don't think it's because Firefox keeps running in the background, because I have restarted the PC several times and it's still logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In this case you should use session cookie for exactly checking when Browser session is
opened - it is the idea behind the function.**

> What you are looking for is something called **Persistent Login Cookie** that is something similar to
>   **"Remember me"** functionality mostly used in login forms. Basically you
>   set encrypted login cookie on user's browser and then can use it for automatic authentication of user.

This answer on Stack Overflow may be helpful: [Improved Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244882/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-remember-me-for-a-website#answer-244907)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that practice, I will implement it!

Comment: No problem @E.Abbott
I would appreciate if you'll set this as an answer for other lost souls to be found as an solution.

Comment: Done, hopefully it'll help other newbies like me!