# session web application

Tags: php, javascript, gwt, web

How can I set a web application to have an infinite session, so that the user doesn't get logged out after some time, even if the web application stays open for years ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: session time can be set in php.ini  I am not sure if there is an upper limit tho.  Of course if the server is restarted they are removed.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire>

This might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use COOKIE rather than SESSION, since SESSION only persists until browser is closed

or perhaps you might consider localStorage for HTML 5

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set infinite `SESSION` on server-side because the session information is constantly deleted and creates new session accordingly

By using the function `session_set_cookie_params` we can set lifetime of the session cookie in seconds.

Refer to this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php