# Can't retrieve cookie value in PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, web

I stuck this code at the top of my login page which should redirect the user back to the home page if they are already logged in, but it doesn't work, it simply does nothing, even though I know the cookies has been set. To be extra sure the cookie had been set I went into chrome settings and checked all the cookies that my website has stored and sure enough, my cookie was set there. I have no idea why this isn't working, it's probably just a silly little error I made, but I've been programming all night, and I figure a fresh set of eyes might spot something I might have missed.

Code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
        header("Location: index.php?content=home");
    }
?>
```

How the cookie is assigned:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$redir = $_GET['redir'];

include('con.php');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='{$user}'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($query);

if($user==""||$pass==""){
    header('Location: ../login.php?error=Please fill out EVERYTHING&redir=' . $redir);
}

else if($numrows < 1){
    header('Location: ../login.php?error=User does not exist&redir=' . $redir);
}

else if($pass !=$array['pass']){
    header('Location: ../login.php?error=Invalid user/pass combo&redir=' . $redir);
}

else{
    setcookie("user", $array['ID']);
    header('Location: ../index.php?content=' . $redir);
}
```

?>

EDIT: Below  is what i am getting when i   `print_r($_COOKIE)`

```
Array
(
    [_okbk] => cd4=true,vi5=0,vi4=1381557924453,vi3=active,vi2=false,vi1=false,cd8=chat,cd6=0,cd5=away,cd3=false,cd2=0,cd1=0,
    [_ok] => 5197-288-10-3215
    [olfsk] => olfsk8855679365806282
    [wcsid] => aqVZBde4DlLmegpG5L3JS16nDXl0aIA9
    [hblid] => oBSPj2E8hdamA4nK5L3JS16nDXrqAaPK
    [_oklv] => 1381563654520,aqVZBde4DlLmegpG5L3JS16nDXl0aIA9
)
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($_COOKIE);` and see what it outputs.

Comment: Maybe you're accessing a wrong index?

Comment: with that much code is really hard to tell the problem

Comment: how are you assigning the cookie?

Comment: I assign the cookie with "setcookie('user', $array['ID'])" and after pasting the value of the cookie in that same chunk of code I know I set it right, it just isn't able to be accessed from other pages for some reason

Comment: so there is no cookie with the index hello so you need to assign first to use

Comment: how are you setting the cookie?

Comment: I did assign the cookie, and when I look through the list of stored cookies in google chrome it's there, the page just isn't seeing it for some odd reason.

Comment: well you are not assigning cookie in code you have given

Comment: Check my edited question, I assign the cookies in the bottom "else" of the code block I added

Comment: And yes it is going to the else block to my knowledge ganeshrj, because the cookie is set when I look in the chrome settings, and it is redirecting me to the page I came from after I log in.

Comment: Try Changing the cookie name to user_name or something else. The post variable and cookie have the same name..

Comment: and your code is vulnerable to sql injection also you are using obsolete mysqli_* api check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189

Comment: I know my code is vulnerable, it is not done, I am focusing on getting my code functional before adding security measures. And ganeshrj, that made no difference, thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Is the 1st block of code in the same page as the cookie setting code?

Comment: No, that block of code is just on the login form page, the actual login code is in a different script

Comment: try print_r($_REQUEST)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting cookie for 0 seconds like `setcookie("user", $array['ID']);`. 3rd parameter in `setcookie` is `$expire` and by default it is `=0`.

```
setcookie("user", $array['ID'], 3600, '/'); # set cookie for 1 hour and for whole domain
```

Comment: I think this may be the problem, but is there any way to make it never expire?

Comment: No. You can just use a far future date. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire

Comment: So there's no way to keep the cookie until I manually delete it?

Comment: No. You can set it far in the future, or re-set it on intervals.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was the domain setting that worked, because when I looked up cookies in my browser I had cookies stored for mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com

Comment: The cookie persists till the session expires . I think the problem was due to the path . I think you were setting the cookie in one path and accessing at a different path . However your problem is solved with Glavic's answer which I think addressed path issue .

Comment: @Uours: I kinda predicted that after he will save timeout issue, that he will come back with question, why must he set cookie for every path/subfolder ;)