# How to keep $_GET value after closing browser php

Tags: php

**First Page:** I have a form that links to the second page when the submit button is pushed.

```
<form action='http://localhost/wordpress/secondpage/' method='get'>
    <input class='changeDataButtons' type='submit' name='activate' value='Activate' />
</form>";
```

**Second Page:** I check if the "Activate" button was pushed and I activate a second menu in my wordpress site.

```
if(isset($_GET['activate']))
{
    my_wp_nav_menu_args();
}
function my_wp_nav_menu_args($args = '')
{
    $args['menu'] = 'Menu 2';
    return $args;                           
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

I also have a form in the second page that link to the first page when the submit button is pushed.

```
<form action='http://localhost/wordpress/firstpage' method='get'>
    <input class='changeDataButtons' type='submit' name='deactivate' value='Deactivate' />
</form>";
```

First Page: I check if the "Deactivate" button was pushed and I activate the first menu in my wordpress site.

```
if(isset($_GET['deactivate']))
{
    my_wp_nav_menu_args();
}
function my_wp_nav_menu_args($args = '')
{
    $args['menu'] = 'Menu 1';
    return $args;                           
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Everything works fine but when I close the browser, $_GET gets to zero and Menu 1 is activated again. Is there a way to keep $_GET value?
I thought about using sessions and set a cookie with an expire time, but I don't want it to expire. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Set a cookie to never expire](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3290474/3849602)

Comment: Either-or, both will work.

Comment: I thought about using sessions and set a cookie with an expire time, but I don't want it to expire.

Comment: @user3677132 check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
setcookie("name", "value", time() * 2, "/");
```

That will expire on *Mon, 18 Apr 2061 06:46:52 GMT*

Answer (score 1):

Sessions and cookies are the best way to do it and make sure they do not expire. The 3rd option would be to grab the IP address and save it to a database with those options set.

Comment: How can I make sure that they do not expire?

Comment: cookie never expire:
setcookie("CookieName", "CookieValue", 2147483647);

Comment: Sessions never expire: session_set_cookie_params(2147483647);

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to get the persons IP address. Then you can save it into a database. This is often used for much more secure logins.

Comment: Don't rely on IP address (neither on any `$_SERVER` variable) to identify a user. It can be an interesting data (warn a user that someone logged-in to his/her account with an unknow IP for example), but don't rely on it.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a session. If session = true, page = 2 else page = 1