# Setting a cookie in WordPress plugin, cookie gets deleted automatically

Tags: php, cookies, wordpress

I'm currently trying my hands on WordPress plugind developement for an exercise and came across some little snag.

The plugin is designed to display a simple poll in a widget on the front page. Once the visitor has voted, I use setcookie to drop a cookie containing his vote for 30 days, and some simple code to change the widget so that it shows the results and the user cannot vote again until a new poll is proposed. The problem is, voting is still possible, the results are never shown. Looking at the logs with the developer's tools, I found that the cookie is deleted the second it lands on the client browser. Does anybody know why, and how I can correct that?

Here's the code. First, the action hook:

```
    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('poll_plugin', __('Polls', 'poll_plugin'), array('description' => __('Simple poll widget', 'poll_plugin')));
    add_action('init', array($this, 'save_votes'));
}
```

Then, the actual action:

```
public function save_votes()
{
    global $wpdb;
    /*Cookie setting, 30 days expiration */
    if ( isset($_POST['option']) && !isset($_COOKIE['Poll_Votes']))
    {
        unset($_COOKIE['Poll_Votes']);
        setcookie('Poll_Votes', $choix, 30 * DAYS_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);

        $choix = $_POST['option'];
        $id_choix = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}poll_options WHERE label = '$choix'");
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}poll_results SET total = total+1 WHERE option_id = '$id_choix'");
    };
    /*Testing the presence of a new poll */
    $vote = $_COOKIE['Poll_Votes'];
    /*If the cookie's value isn't found in the db, the poll's changed, so we reset the cookie*/
    if (is_null($wpdb->get_var("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}poll_options WHERE label = '$vote'")))
    {
        setcookie('Poll_Votes', '', time()-3600);
    }
}
```

Quick note here, I already tried commenting the line designed to unset the cookie, it changed nothing.

The only other time where the cookie is mentioned is via the $_COOKIE global, in a isset().

And lastly, please forgive my english, I'm french :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a cookie to never expire](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire)

Comment: is `DAYS_IN_SECONDS` defined as `0` perhaps?

Comment: The fact is I made a typo, it was supposed to be DAY_IN_SECONDS, but I checked and it's correctly defined in the wp-includes. I also tried with time()+60*60*24*30 to the same result.

Comment: I'd also check to make sure the cookiepath and cookie_domain constants are correct in that case, anything off could be causing your issue

Comment: also according to [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) cookie creation is sent with the headers, so when you go to call it 7 lines after creation, it's not technically there yet.

Comment: @iam-decoder That's correct - the `$_COOKIE` array is built on page load. If OP want to have immediate access he should add the key in `$_COOKIE` himself.

Comment: Both constants are correcty defined, I double-checked.
And for the part of the cookie sent before the headers, that's why the action hook is set on "init", It ensures the action save_votes is run before anything else.