# Cookie Laravel 5-4

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I try to work with Cookie in my website ,but always it marked as session and dont stay for all the time declared , it desespere after the browser close:

Here is my code to create the Cookie :

```
Cookie::queue('credits_sv', serialize($data), 60 * 24 * 30 * 365);
```

Here is my code to get data of Cookie :

```
Cookie::get('credits_sv')
```

Here the result :

[image]

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Maybe 30 years is quite too long for a cookie ... try with some shorter time

Comment: Thank you, it's good now , make the comment as answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently have the cookie lifetime set to 30 years. I think you really meant it to be 1 year instead of 30.

Moreover, from this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3290474/7377984):

> If you set a date past 2038 in PHP, the number will wrap around and
>   you'll get a cookie that expires instantly.

**So to fix the code, change it to:**

`Cookie::queue('credits_sv', serialize($data), 60 * 24 * 365);`