# How to set never-expiring cookie in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to set a cookie that "never" expires, which means setting it to `2^31 - 1` which is an absolute value/date rather than an offset, to avoid the [2038 wrap-around bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire).

To set a cookie in ASP.NET Core:

```
Response.Cookies.Append("name", "value", new CookieOptions() { /*...*/ })
```

I can't use `DateTime.MaxValue` and so on due to the bug. What should I use for `CookieOptions`?

Comment: The site you're building nor the machine you're wanting to set the cookie on will be around in twenty years from now.

Comment: @CodeCaster I know, but I'd like to know how to do this regardless. We have a system in our server room that apparently has been running for over 25 years (cobol), so yeah. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to hardcode the value like this:

```
var co = new CookieOptions();
co.Expires = new DateTimeOffset(2038, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(0));
```

That avoids the [2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: This code doesn't avoid it. In fact it makes sure the 2038 problem will still exist in the code even when underlying protocols have already fixed it. A quick calculation tells me that I'll be working until 2047 so I just can't leave it like this, any other solutions? :)

Comment: @Housy Been a while since I looked at this code - what it wrong with it? If you have a better solution, post it and I'll mark yours as correct.

Comment: The problem is that it will stop working at 2 January 2038. I wonder if adding 20 years to the current time is problematic for all recent browsers. Might have to test this if I find the time.

Comment: @Housy Oh I see what you mean - well everyone considers 2038 as a hard reality, so I just worked around it. Would be nice not to deal with it at all, but I doubt that's possible without some hackery. Update me if you think of something.

Comment: Even Google uses 2038 as max-age for cookies. I just checked google.com in my browser:  https://i.imgur.com/6qXbiDA.png

Comment: @BrunoCassol Good to know, thanks. Interesting / scary that's it's the consent cookie that lives "forever"... "Here, take my info, yes *of course* you can keep it forever!" :-) :-(

Comment: Chrome as of January 12th, 2023 set a max cap limit for the days to 400 days.

No cookie can have an expiration date of over 400 days. As Chrome will cap at 400 days regards.

Article - https://developer.chrome.com/blog/cookie-max-age-expires/