# Set Session Cookie Expire

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I have code that sets a session cookie, but I want it to persist beyond the single session.  Is there a way to do this, or how would I convert it to a regular cookie that I can set to a longer expire time?

This is the code I call in the primary page to check for the session (age validation)...

```
session_start();
    if(! isset( $_SESSION['age_verification'] ) or $_SESSION['age_verification'] != true ) die( header("Location: checkage.php?url=http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]") );
```

Then from there, I call the following to check for the validation (form is not included as it is not necessary, but it creates the session cookie if yes is clicked).

```
<?php
session_start();

if( isset( $_POST['yes'] ) )
{
    $_SESSION['age_verification'] = true;

    if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) )
    {
        die( header('Location: ' . $_GET['url'] ) ); 
    } 
    else
    {
        die( header('Location: index.php') );
    }
}
elseif( isset( $_POST['no'] ) )
{
    $_SESSION['age_verification'] = false;
}

if( isset( $_SESSION['age_verification'] ) and $_SESSION['age_verification'] != true ) die( header('Location: http://www.bing.com') );

?>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

Answer (score 0):

Its not really something you necessarily want to do but this thread is quite relevant:

[Set a cookie to never expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire)

Comment: Tried setting the field, appears to not work for session cookie.  Any other thoughts?