# Is there any limit on an expired date in the cookie browser?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set cookies in a javascript file, and I need to set the "max-age" of cookies for 2 years.
Probably the cookie updated to 1 year and a few days only.

Does someone know if there is any limit on the expired date?

My test in dev-tools that doesn't work:
document.cookie='test=res;path=/;**max-age=31619000**';

Comment: Accoring to this comment it does not have a limit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3290474/7081176. However some browsers might enforce a limit while others don't.

Comment: I think chrome family of browsers recently made a change in this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

400 days (or less depending on the browser).

[HTTP Working Group Specification](https://httpwg.org/http-extensions/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis.html#name-the-expires-attribute) states the following:

> The user agent MUST limit the maximum value of the Expires attribute. The limit SHOULD NOT be greater than 400 days (34560000 seconds) in the future. The RECOMMENDED limit is 400 days in the future, but the user agent MAY adjust the limit (see [Section 7.2](https://httpwg.org/http-extensions/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis.html#cookie-policy)). Expires attributes that are greater than the limit MUST be reduced to the limit.

Explanation from [chrome status](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4887741241229312)

> When cookies are set with an explicit Expires/Max-Age attribute the
> value will now be capped to no more than 400 days in the future.
> Previously, there was no limit and cookies could expire as much as
> multiple millennia in the future.
>
> 400 days was
> chosen as a round number close to 13 months in duration. 13 months was
> chosen to ensure that sites one visits roughly once a year (e.g.,
> picking health insurance benefits) will continue to work.

Comment: Why not link to the RFC directly?

Comment: I considered documentation of an actual implementation (in the browser with the highest market share) with a supporting quote from the RFC to be more valuable.

Comment: @mousetail — Your edit misattributes the quoted material.

Comment: Ok I changed it so it links both

Comment: The attributions are still not associated with the correct material.

Comment: Yea I noticed, fixing it now

Comment: Is there info about max expiry date for browsers other than Chrome?